# Using SMO on web server with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, smo

Is it required to have anything SQL Server related installed on a web server in order to make use of SMO? I've built a web app that programmatically creates a SQL Agent job, adds a step (which ultimately fires of dtexec to run an SSIS package), and executes.

This works fine on my local machine which has SQL client tools installed, however when I move to a web server, I get reference issues and I'm starting to think it's due to something not being installed.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.

Comment: Technically you should just need to copy all the missing assemblies, which were probably automatically GAC'd on your local machine with SQL Client tools installer.  But it might be easier to just install the SQL Client tools on the web server as well.

Comment: I really want to avoid installing anything more on to the web server if possible. I see this assembly in the GAC, but can't find an actual dll to put in my bin directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rat hole.

The problem is that once you locate that assembly and copy it to the bin folder of your application it will complain about a completely different one.. or even the same file simply due to missing dependencies.

For more information read this: http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/10/20/how-i-fixed-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-smo-version10-0-0-0-issue/

That site lists the files you need and the fact you need to register and gac a few files.  Quite frankly, you are much better off just biting the bullet and install the client tools on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your application requires this assembly in its bin directory to function. This error means that the server doesn't have the SMO (and its dependant) assemblies.

Back in your solution in Visual Studio, right click on the assembly above, and select/change the "Copy Local" to "True". Copy this for each SMO assembly that you've referenced.

When you publish your application, this will bring those .DLLs on your development machine along in your published bin directory.

- **Check your web.config** file for any references as well
- search your code for SqlClrProvider

[image]

Comment: I don't see any reference to this assembly though. I've referenced the following 5 assemblies, which I've made sure are in my bin folder once published: microsoft.sqlserver.connectioninfo.dll, microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc.dll, microsoft.sqlserver.smo.dll, microsoft.sqlserver.smoextended.dll, microsoft.sqlserver.sqlenum.dll

Comment: Also, I tried the Copy Local = True on these 5 dlls, but they don't copy over and I'm guessing that's because they're in the GAC

Comment: Check my web.config for what? I don't see any reference to the mentioned assembly